# VSTS How to Trigger a Deployment Containing Multiple Release Definitions

Tags: azure-devops, release, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have 20 release definitions that need to be deployed together for a deployment to an environment.

Is there a way to link the release definitions and manually trigger a "global" release to deploy all 20 release definitions to a specific environment?

At this moment we manually start each release, lots of clicking!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create/manage releases through the VSTS API.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases

specifically look at the example for "Start deployment on an environment".

An example scenario could look like this

1. Create a release from the API

   ```
   POST https://{instance}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version={4.0-preview.4}
   ```
2. The response "A Release object" will contain key elements you need to trigger environment deployments.  You'll need the Release ID and the environment ID(s). 
   Find this in the response release ID will be returned in the response, save it, this is your key to automating environment deployments later
3. Let's say the release ID created was 77 and the environment (Production) id was 3
4. The final step is to kick off a release:

   ```
   PATCH https://{instance}/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/77/environments/3

   {
       "status": "inProgress",
       "scheduledDeploymentTime": null,
       "comment": null
   }
   ```

Comment: This has us headed in the right direction.  Thank you!!  After looking over the link I am still not sure how for a release definition to deploy a preexisting release to an environment.  Do you have any syntax examples?

Comment: @Brian I've updated my answer with a scenario where you create and then manually trigger a release.  In your case you would be doing this 20 times over per release

Comment: Thank you for this example.  The one difference is that the release will already exist and we are promoting from stage to prod.  What is the unique value we can use to build the request so the correct release definition, id and environment are used?

Comment: @Brian, see the documentation I originally posted, specially "List Releases".  You can provide a filter to get the specific release you are interested in

Answer (score 1):

There is no such settings to trigger multiple release definitions.

For now a release environment can be triggered with three types: After release, After environment, Manual only.

If you manually deploy, you should create releases of the different release definitions separately.

The workaround is add all the tasks from different release definitions into one release definition (**merge multiple release definitions into one release definition**), and then create a release for the release definition.

Comment: do you know if there are any plans to add such a feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a build definition and link that build definition to all of your releases with Continuous Deployment trigger turned on.

Whenever a build is completed, the release on all the 20 RDs will be triggered.

Now this build could actually produce some meaningful artifact or it can act as a trigger point for all the release definitions.